# Como iterar um array um determinado número de vezes em PHP no CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, iterator

Eu tenho 2 arrays, um vazio( vamos chamar de tenStatesArray) que eu quero que contenha 10 valores e outro contendo 26 valores( vamos chamar de statesArray). Como passar os primeiros 10 elementos desse array que contem 26  para o tenStatesArray  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que você queira os 10 primeiros elementos, você pode usar a função `array_slice` nativa do php.

```
$tenStatesArray = array_slice($statesArray, 0, 10);
```